# Github API Etags are invalidated because token has expired and causing spike in API limit

Tags: github, flask, caching, gunicorn, github-api

Context about setup: We are working with GitHub Apps, the App hook is running Gunicorn workers using flask, and Jenkins/Airflow or other services running checks in background that are resource expensive eg: build  for a relatively large code base that can take several hours to complete, only after all checks are complete a pull request is allowed to merge.
Whenever app needs to make request to GitHub, first it requests and receives a token for every installation using this URL `https://{github_server}/api/v3/app/installations/{installation_id}/access_tokens` and this token is valid only for 1 hour. Then we use this token until expire time to make consecutive requests to GitHub. GitHub sends back ETag for most of request urls eg:
`https://{github_server}/api/v3/repos/{org}/{repo}/commits/{sha}/check-suites` or `https://{github_server}/api/v3/repos/{org}/{repo}/check-suites/{suite_id}/check-runs` which will have these Response Headers

```
ETag: W/"{some_tag_value}"
Vary: Accept, Authorization, Cookie, X-GitHub-OTP
```

along with several other headers. Etags are then stored in cache along with response and url. When we re-request on this URL by same Etag and token it can return 200 or 304 status code, depending upon if the check suite has changed or not. There are several reasons why it may have changed: another app added extra check-suite for that PR and sha, user re-requested the check-runs.
The problem arises when it is gets 200 status code which accounts towards API limit, while 304 does not.
For the time Pull requests are still open and running checks, we update status of individual checks several time in the process. We want to maximize the use of cache and 304 status type requests to GitHub. Because the check status may be updated after several hours, it would require us to send request with new token as previous would have expired, and since Etags depend on Fields in `Vary` header that Etag is no longer valid even if the check-suite didn't change, but because token changed. This invalidates the cache more often then it is required to.

1. Is there a better way to make requests and update check statuses via github apps, that would not invalidated cache so quickly and keep API limit under control ?
2. Another concern is that since gunicorn workers are different process they are not able to share tokens even during that 1 hour time span. We can store token in cache along with other info, but that raises security concerns. Does flask provides in-memory mechanism that is more suited for storing tokens and sharing across multiple instances ?

Things that I have tried/Additional Context

1. We are working based on info provided in [Github API Conditional requests](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#conditional-requests). This has similar `Vary` header suggesting authorization to be consistent for all requests.
2. For caching we were trying to use [Requests-Cache](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) python library, I also tried to build a simplistic design right into our flask hook to allow manual caching to allow additional fields to be stored such as token and expire time.